# Examples of majority rule/mob rule communities that have succeed long term and don't degrade to lowest common denominator?

Tags: user-behavior, moderators, site-administration, community-standards

A recent episode of The Orville - [Majority Rule](http://orville.wikia.com/wiki/Majority_Rule) - had an interesting premise: the entire society's laws were voted on by everyone all the time. The majority vote wins and that is how laws are created and how guilt/innocence is determined.

Are there any real world examples of this? I'd be interested in something "in real life", but I suspect that's not the case. Are there any virtual communities that have a simple majority rule system? If so, how do they keep the entire system from falling to populist changes and remain stable over time?

Every community I've participated in has some level of "upper class" citizens. Usually these are elected community representatives, appointed moderators or simply community admins. I'm looking for a flat structure.

Comment: This is the premise of *Animal Farm*.  Such a system will always fail.  "*All men are equal but some are more equal than others*"

Comment: In my opinion, a group gets together around a common vision or identity. There has to be somebody and individual/individuals who upholds the identity or vision. A mob doesn’t have a vision or identity, to start off with, and without that individual, that vision will be lost and the mob will most likely dissipate over time.